# Averaging by one column that has NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset where one column has a lot of NaNs and all others are normal.

How can I group and average by the column that has NaNs?

Please note that values in column one are repetitive, so I can't just use ffill and groupby because it would skew my dataset. One value can occur more then once.

```
   column_1  column_2  column_3
0      45.0         3         2
1       NaN         4         6
2       NaN         7         2
3      37.0         1         1
4       NaN         6         4
5       NaN         2         7
6       NaN         4         5
7      45.0         2         2
8       NaN         1         1
9       NaN         3         3
```

To:

```
   column_1  column_2  column_3
0        45       4.6      3.33
1        37      3.25      4.25
2        45       2         2
```

Comment: you can use `ffill` to forward fill the column 1 and then use groupby as usual. check my answer for details.

Comment: Thanks for adding that detail. Can you add it to the example dataset as well?, along with expected output

Comment: Updated my answer based on your updated question. let me know if that solved it

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Based on your updated question, you can use a `shift()` based grouper to solve this groupby. Note, you will still need `ffill()` to fill the NA values as before.

```
df['column_1'] = df['column_1'].ffill()
df.groupby((df['column_1']!=df['column_1'].shift()).cumsum()).mean().reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
   column_1  column_2  column_3
0      45.0  4.666667  3.333333
1      37.0  3.250000  4.250000
2      45.0  2.000000  2.000000
```

---

**Explanation:**

The grouping condition basically compares the shifted column with its previous values, and then uses `cumsum()` to cumulate this so as to create new groups for each time a value changes in the sequence in column 1.

```
list((df['column_1']!=df['column_1'].shift()).cumsum())
```

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

So the groupby happens on this "hidden" column.

Comment: I have repetitive values in column 1, this approach would throw off my dataset by a lot.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the update, I will let you know once I finish collecting my dataset. Hopefully by tomorrow.